# Finite set proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to prove this:

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N} $ be a subset. Suppose that there is some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a \leq M$ for all $a \in A$. Prove that $A$ is finite.

What i know about this is:

- Since $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$. Then $A\prec\mathbb{N}$ and there is an injective fuction from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$
- And since $M\in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \leq M$ then A is bounded sup. by M.

Do I need this to prove? Or how can I prove this?

Comment: Every subset of the natural numbers has a least element. Then use the hypothesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that $A$ is not finite. That is, $A$ is countably infinite.

We also have that there exists some $M\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a\leq M$ for every $a\in A$.

By our assumption, we must have that there exist some $a'\in A$ such that $a'>M$. If there were no such $a'$, then we would gave that $A\subseteq \{1,\cdots, M\}=:[M]$. The set $[M]$ is clearly finite and every subset of a finite set is at most finite.

This would contradict our assumption that $A$ is countably infinite.

But then we must have that $a'\leq M$ as $a'\in A$ and we have shown $a'>M$. Which is impossible. That means our original supposition was wrong and $A$ must be finite.

Answer (score 1):

$A \subseteq [0, M]$ (or $[1, M]$ depending on how you treat natural numbers). You can show that any $M$ in $[0, M]$ is finite through induction on $M$ (I'll leave this to you). Thus, $A$ is a subset of a finite set. Hence, $A$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ and $a\leq M$ for all $a\in A$. Assume $A$ is infinite. Then there must be $a$ in $A$ such that $a>M$. The details are left to the reader.